# C++ shadowing variable name

Tags: c++

If a C++ class member function accesses a variable name that is overloaded with definitions both as a member variable of the class and a variable in the global scope of the member function’s definition, which one will the member function actually access?  The scenario is like this:

SomeClass.h:

```
class   SomeClass
{
    int Num;
    void    OperateOnNum();
};
```

SomeClass.cpp:

```
#include "SomeClass.h"
int Num;
void    SomeClass::OperateOnNum()
{
    Num = 0;
}
```

Which Num will OperateOnNum operate on?  Neither Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 nor GCC (Version: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2) issues a warning.

Comment: FYI that's shadowing not overloading. Overloading is having multiple functions with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: The one in the nearest scope, i.e. the member.

Comment: Overloading - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class variable shadows the global variable. If you want to access the global variable do it like this:

```
void SomeClass::OperateOnNum()
{
    ::Num = 0;
}
```

There's no warnings, because that's just how the language works.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `this` and global scope resolution to dissambiguate between the two

```
this->Num; // refers to the member Num
::Num;     // refers to the global Num
```

A good design though, shouldn't have to resort to such methods. You can mark member names and globals (which are a "don't" on their own) accordingly :

```
_name;  // member name prefixed with _
m_name; // member name prefixed with m_
global_name; // global name - prefixed with global_
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the class member parameter **shadows** the global variable. Thus you see it in the scope of the method.