# Problem with putting data from csv file into table [C++]

Tags: c++, csv

I'm beginner at c++, and I have to put data (integers) from csv file into table. I tried to use ifstream, read data as lines and then convert it into int and it works, but when i try to put this int into table it says: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream}' and 'int')|.

```
int data[1000000];

void getData(){
 //getting wej data
    char read[256];
    GetPrivateProfileString("data","wej","fail",read,256,".\\zad1.ini");
    cout<<read<<endl;
//------------
//reading data
    int i=0; //index
    int x=0;
    ifstream data(read);
    string line;
    while(getline(data,line))
        {
        stringstream  lineStream(line);
        while(getline(lineStream,line,','))
            {
                stringstream d(line);
                d>>x;
                data[i] = x;
                i++;
            }
        }
//------------
}
```

Comment: `data[i] = x;` ifstream does not have an operator []. Your bug appears that you have used `data` for 2 different variables. Once you do `ifstream data(read);` the previous `int data[1000000];` is no longer visible in the scope.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528453/c-shadowing-variable-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528453/c-shadowing-variable-name)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't notice that.